# Optimize the calculation of horizontal and vertical adjacency using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization, vectorization

I have following cells:

```
cells = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                  [1, 1, 0],
                  [1, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 1],
                  [1, 0, 0],
                  [1, 1, 1]])
```

and I want to calculate horizontal and vertical adjacencies to come to this result:

```
# horizontal adjacency 
array([[3, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 1]])

# vertical adjacency 
array([[6, 2, 1],
       [5, 1, 0],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

The actual sollution looks like this:

```
def get_horizontal_adjacency(cells):
    adjacency_horizontal = np.zeros(cells.shape, dtype=int)
    for y in range(cells.shape[0]):
        span = 0
        for x in reversed(range(cells.shape[1])):
            if cells[y, x] > 0:
                span += 1
            else:
                span = 0
            adjacency_horizontal[y, x] = span
    return adjacency_horizontal

def get_vertical_adjacency(cells):
    adjacency_vertical = np.zeros(cells.shape, dtype=int)
    for x in range(cells.shape[1]):
        span = 0
        for y in reversed(range(cells.shape[0])):
            if cells[y, x] > 0:
                span += 1
            else:
                span = 0
            adjacency_vertical[y, x] = span
    return adjacency_vertical
```

The Algorithm is basically (for horizontal adjacency):

1. loop throgh rows
2. loop backward throgh columns
3. if the x, y value of cells **is not** zero, add 1 to the actual span
4. if the x, y value of cells **is** zero, reset actual span to zero
5. set the span as new x, y value of the resulting array

Since I need to loop two times over all array elements this is slow for bigger arrays (e.g. images).

Is there a way to improve the algorithm using vectorization or some other numpy magic?

**Summary**:

Great suggestions have been made by joni and Mark Setchell!

I created a [small Repo](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/SO-Improve-Performance-of-Numpy-Iterations) with a sample image and a python file with the comparisons. The results are astonishing:

- Original Approach: 3.675 s
- Using Numba: 0.002 s
- Using Cython: 0.005 s

Comment: Are you trying to do [opencv's distanceTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga8a0b7fdfcb7a13dde018988ba3a43042)?

Comment: no I want to implement https://www.evryway.com/largest-interior/ in Python

Comment: IMHO, the easiest way to speed up your functions would be rewriting both in [Cython](https://cython.org/). It's more or less the same code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a really quick attempt at this with Numba but have not checked it too thoroughly though the results seem about right:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# https://stackoverflow.com/q/69854335/2836621
# magick -size 1920x1080 xc:black -fill white -draw "circle 960,540 960,1040" -fill black -draw "circle 960,540 960,800" a.png

import cv2
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def get_horizontal_adjacency(cells):
    adjacency_horizontal = np.zeros(cells.shape, dtype=int)
    for y in range(cells.shape[0]):
        span = 0
        for x in reversed(range(cells.shape[1])):
            if cells[y, x] > 0:
                span += 1
            else:
                span = 0
            adjacency_horizontal[y, x] = span
    return adjacency_horizontal

@nb.jit('void(uint8[:,::1], int32[:,::1])',parallel=True)
def nb_get_horizontal_adjacency(cells, result):
    for y in nb.prange(cells.shape[0]):
        span = 0
        for x in range(cells.shape[1]-1,-1,-1):
            if cells[y, x] > 0:
                span += 1
            else:
                span = 0
            result[y, x] = span
    return 

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('a.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

%timeit get_horizontal_adjacency(im)

result = np.zeros((im.shape[0],im.shape[1]),dtype=np.int32)
%timeit nb_get_horizontal_adjacency(im, result)
```

The timings are good, showing 4000x speed-up, if it works correctly:

```
In [15]: %timeit nb_get_horizontal_adjacency(im, result)
695 µs ± 9.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [17]: %timeit get_horizontal_adjacency(im)
2.78 s ± 44.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Input**

Input image was created in 1080p dimensions, i.e. 1920x1080, with **ImageMagick** using:

```
magick -size 1920x1080 xc:black -fill white -draw "circle 960,540 960,1040" -fill black -draw "circle 960,540 960,800" a.png
```

[image]

**Output (contrast adjusted)**

[image]

Comment: `for x in range(cells.shape[1]-1,0,-1):` needs to be `range(cells.shape[1]-1,-1,-1)`. if not, the last x will be `1` instead of `0`

Comment: @LukasWeber Thank you for the correction - I have updated the answer. Funnily enough, that was precisely the part I hadn't checked thoroughly!

Comment: Can you explain why nb.prange() is only used in the first for loop?

Comment: Numba parallelises (i.e. distributes) across your CPU cores any loops written with `prange`. If you have 4 CPU cores it will do 1/4 of the loop on each core. If you then do another `prange` inside in an inner loop, you don't really have 16 cores so there is (I think) little point splitting things further. I may be wrong and have not timed it, but in general, I tend to make the outermost loop parallelised and assume there's little more to be had from trying to split things further in inner loops. If that is wrong, somebody PLEASE tell me!!!

Comment: would I want to use uint8[:, ::1, :] for a multiband image or uint8[:, :, ::1]?

Answer (score 4):

As already stated in the comments, this is a perfect example where it's easier to just rewrite the function by means of Cython or Numba. Since Mark already provided a Numba solution, let me provide a Cython solution. First, let's time his solution on my machine for a fair comparison:

```py
In [5]: %timeit nb_get_horizontal_adjacency(im, result)
836 µs ± 36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Assuming the image `im` is a `np.ndarray` with `dtype=np.uint8`, a parallelised Cython solution looks like this:

```py
In [6]: %%cython -f -a -c=-O3 -c=-march=native -c=-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp

from cython import boundscheck, wraparound, initializedcheck
from libc.stdint cimport uint8_t, uint32_t
from cython.parallel cimport prange
import numpy as np

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
@initializedcheck(False)
def cy_get_horizontal_adjacency(uint8_t[:, ::1] cells):
    cdef int nrows = cells.shape[0]
    cdef int ncols = cells.shape[1]
    cdef uint32_t[:, ::1] adjacency_horizontal = np.zeros((nrows, ncols), dtype=np.uint32)
    cdef int x, y, span
    for y in prange(nrows, nogil=True, schedule="static"):
        span = 0
        for x in reversed(range(ncols)):
            if cells[y, x] > 0:
                span += 1
            else:
                span = 0
            adjacency_horizontal[y, x] = span
    return np.array(adjacency_horizontal, copy=False)
```

On my machine, this is nearly two times faster:

```py
In [7]: %timeit cy_get_horizontal_adjacency(im)
431 µs ± 4.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Cool - nice work!

Comment: Hello joni! Thats my first approach to cython. With my compiled script your approach is a bit slower than Numba (see the edited question). Can you maybe have a look if I compiled everything correctly? https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/SO-Improve-Performance-of-Numpy-Iterations/tree/main/cy

Comment: You should set the right compiler flags. On Windows it should be `# distutils: extra_compile_args=/Ox /arch:AVX2 /openmp` at the top of the `*.pyx` file. However, in my experience, the MSVC compiler is quite bad at SIMD auto-vectorization compared to gcc/clang (that's the purpose of the `-march=native` flag for the gcc/clang compiler). So I wouldn't be surprised if the Numba solution is faster on Windows.